# how to parse query argument using vertx?

Tags: java, rest, vert.x

I wanted to check if we can use getparam to parse start_time and end_time from the below request URL

```
https://[--hostname--]/sample_app/apthroughput/getAllControllers?start_time=<start time value>&end_time=<end time value>&label=<selected label>
```

Answer (score 7):

The parsing of a query string is quite straightforward except for when there are multiple values for the same query param.

```
e.g.: https://[--hostname--]/sample_app/apthroughput/getAllControllers?type=xxx&type=yyy
```

in such cases the code below helps getting all the params of a kind in `List<String>`

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47790106/accepting-list-of-parameters-of-same-key-in-vertx-api) gives an idea. Copying from it:

```
HttpServerRequest request = RoutingContext.request();
MultiMap params =  request.params();
List<String> param = params.getAll("personId");
Here you can get list of personId. URI be like

localhost:8081/myApi?personId=1&personId=2&personId=3
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();

    server.requestHandler(request -> {

        String startTime = request.getParam("start_time");
        String endTime = request.getParam("end_time");

        // This handler gets called for each request that arrives on the server
        HttpServerResponse response = request.response();
        response.putHeader("content-type", "text/plain");

        // Write to the response and end it
        response.end(String.format("Got start time %s, end time %s", startTime, endTime));
    });

    server.listen(8888);
}
```

Open http://localhost:8888/?start_time=20161014&end_time=20161015 to see the results.

Comment: I did the same thing but request.getParam("end_time") is returning null. I tried to print request.query() to check all the params passed but its printing only start_time. any idea what can be the reason?

Comment: Malformed parameter names, probably. What does your full URL look like now?

Comment: https://[--hostname--]/acp_sample_app/throughput/getAll?start_time=<start_time value>&end_time=<end time value>&label=<selected label>

Comment: `http://localhost:10210/acp_sample_app/throughput/getAll?start_time=1234567&end_time=12345678&label=123 ` . Also the path i am using router.route("/sample_app/throughput/getall).handler(...)

Comment: Happy to hear. Please mark correct answer, so other Vertx users could reuse it.

Comment: I think the best way to do is as in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47790106/accepting-list-of-parameters-of-same-key-in-vertx-api

Answer (score 1):

You can get the parameter String representation but you need to convert the value yourself.

Comment: Can you help me with router.route handler?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is (a bit) late response, but in Vert.X 3.9 to get *start_time* and *end_time* parameters you can get them this way:

```
public void getAllControllersHandler(RoutingContext context) {
   Mutlimap parameters = context.request().params();
   String start_time = parameters.get("start_time");
   String end_time = parameters.get("end_time");
   // now do what you need to with retrieved values :)
}
```

Also, when your endpoint has to look like this when you are passing it to your *Route get()* (I presume you are using HTTP Get method):

```
Router router = Router.router(vertx);
router.get("/sample_app/apthroughput/getAllControllers").handler(this::getAllControllersHandler);
```

Hope it helps.

**P.S.** If this solves problem please mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

@OrkunOzen's answer is good, but the MultiMap uses case-insensitive keys.

For more precise control, you can dig into the code to find this util function called from `HttpServerRequest.params()` ->
`io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpUtils.params(String uri)`

This code will give you total control:

```
QueryStringDecoder queryStringDecoder = new QueryStringDecoder(uri);
Map<String, List<String>> prms = queryStringDecoder.parameters();
```