# accepting list of parameters of same key in vertx api

Tags: java, rest, vert.x

How to accept list of parameter in same key in router GET method.
e.g I have a query parameter name as 'personId'. but in get request there can be multiple(list of) personId are coming. How to handle this in vertx. I couldnt find any such method in `HttpServerRequest` Class.
I have another option to accept single parameter but with comma separated ids. But isn't it wrong? Isn't there any other way?

I think the URI should like `localhost:8081/myApi?personId=1&personId=2&personId=3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FInally found it.

```
HttpServerRequest request = RoutingContext.request();
MultiMap params =  request.params();
List<String> param = params.getAll("personId");
```

Here you can get list of personId.
URI be like

`localhost:8081/myApi?personId=1&personId=2&personId=3`